# Custom Binding and TransportWithMessageCredential

Tags: c#, wcf-binding

I have this:

```
BasicHttpBinding myB = new BasicHttpBinding();
myB.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
myB.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
myB.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

and i would apply (without config) to:

```
var bind = new CustomBinding();
```

How can i do?

Comment: Can you be more clear in what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure,
I try to convert my BasicHttpBinding in a customBinding and I miss part Security. Thanks.